# Is it possible to have multiple database connections stored in a single connection pool?

Tags: sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

I have a problem where to perform an operation, switching should happen between multiple databases, and instead of closing and opening connections or keeping all database connections live, it is more efficient to store them in connection pool, so is the only option to create multiple connection pools or is there a way around it.

I have tried reading documentation of sqlalchemy, this documentation was vague and all operations on pools were not given and took help of chatgpt, and it is giving wrong results, and after cross checking it after trying it in code, it is apologizing, and I looked up to previous stackoverflow questions, the answers I found didn't clear me up totally.

Answer (score 0):

Pools are tied to  a single database, so a shared pool isn't feasible. However a `Session` can accept a [binds](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.params.binds) parameter which maps SQLAlchemy objects to engines.

You might also want to look at Flask-SQLAlchemy's [binds](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/binds/#multiple-databases-with-binds) feature.